# Seeking - Gurugram, (Haryana India) tehsil land use\Land cover statistics

Tags: data, india, land-use

I need landuse and land cover statistics for GURUGRAM district's four tehsils named-

- Gurugram,
- Manesar,
- Sohna,
- Farrukhnagar.

LULC layers may be like Agricultural land, Builtup area, Open area, Wasteland, hilly area etc.

Comment: Here is a [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/datameet) where I found few good .kml files on Indian States and Tehsils.
People have asked [similar questions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datameet/CLj4yjZ54E0) as your's. Maybe they can help you.

Comment: Thanks @sinhavartika. But there is no appropriate solution for landuse information, at link provided by you

Comment: @GopalKrishna you can ask them for help. They put significant efforts in finding and collecting data.